# Authorizing the REST calls with RouteLocatorBuilder

Tags: java, spring, routes

**Background**

My use case is to authenticate the calls using a Gateway. I assume that all the calls must have  `user_id` and a `token`. I have an API that will take both user_id, token and return a boolean after checking that it's a valid request or not.

**Current Work**

I have written a Gateway configuration which is working fine in routing the APIs to concerned micro-service but it's not working fine for authentication.

**working code,**

```
@Configuration
public class RouteConfig {
 @Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("path_route", r -> r.path("app1/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("app1/(?<segment>.*)",
                                "app1/${segment}"))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8099"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Firsly , I need to get the Headers variables and then make a POST call to an API which returns BOOLEAN response. If its true then the above code should call. Otherwise the call should be rejected.

**Tried to get Headers value**

```
@Configuration
public class RouteConfig {
 @Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder,@RequestHeader("user_id")
            String userId,@RequestHeader("token")
            String token) {

System.out.println(userId);
System.out.println(token);

        return builder.routes()
                .route("path_route", r -> r.path("app1/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("app1/(?<segment>.*)",
                                "app1/${segment}"))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8099"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

But its not working and application crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a `GatewayFilter` to check each request on your gateway.

```
@Component
public class AuthFilter implements GatewayFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();

        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
        if (!headers.containsKey("user_id") || !headers.containsKey("token"))
            return this.onError(exchange, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

        String userId = request.getHeaders().getOrEmpty("user_id").get(0);
        String token = request.getHeaders().getOrEmpty("token").get(0);

        Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("user_id", userId);
        body.put("token", token);
        WebClient client = WebClient.builder().build();
        boolean ok = client
                .post()
                .uri("your/auth/api")
                .body(Mono.just(body), Map.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Boolean.class)
                .blockFirst();

        if (!ok)
            return this.onError(exchange, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

    private Mono<Void> onError(ServerWebExchange exchange, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(httpStatus);
        return response.setComplete();
    }
}
```

and apply the filter to your route configuration. Not sure if the configuration is correct and the rewrite is applied correctly.

```
@Configuration
public class RouteConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AuthFilter filter;

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("path_route", r -> r.path("app1/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.filters(filter).rewritePath("app1/(?<segment>.*)",
                                "app1/${segment}"))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8099"))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Note that this code is untested, just to give you an idea how you may solve your issue.

Comment: thanks for sharing this answer.I have updated your code with a RestTemplate POST call to get the validation result as your current code is not working.









**Your code :**
 boolean ok = client
                .post()
                .uri("your/auth/api")
                .body(Mono.just(body), Map.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Boolean.class)
                .blockFirst();






**Replaced with :**
ResponseEntity<Boolean> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("your/auth/api", httpEntity, Boolean.class);

Comment: Was not sure if you were using WebMVC or Webflux. Glad the code helps you anyway.